# Codeigniter multilanguage - select from ajax - session problem

Tags: ajax, session, codeigniter, select, multilingual

i want to make the site with multi languages and selecting the language with ajax and the different words will be selected from database and i want to use session[lang],and i don’t want to use GET[lang].
i’m trying from 5 days to make this but i try so many variants and i’m confused now

now i’m here:

i have **model -> Langs ->**

```
function set_langs($arg)  {
  $this->session->unset_userdata(‘lang’);
  $this->session->set_userdata(‘lang’, $arg);
  return $arg;
}
function get_langs()  {
  return $this->session->userdata(‘lang’);
}
```

in the **Home controller ->**

```
public function index(){
  if($this->session->userdata(‘lang’)==’‘){
  $this->Langs->set_langs(‘en’);
  $glang[‘lang’] = $this->Langs->get_langs();
  }else{
  $glang[‘lang’] = $this->Langs->get_langs();
  }
$this->load->view(‘header’, $glang);
}
 public function set()
{
  if($_POST && $_POST[‘lang’] != NULL) {
    $this->Langs->set_langs($_POST[‘lang’]);
    $return[‘error’] = false;
    $return[‘msg’] = $this->session->userdata(‘lang’).’ ok!’;
    echo json_encode($return);
  }else{...}
```

}

and in the **header.php -> in the JS ->**

```
$.ajax({
  type: “POST”,
  url: “index.php/home/set”,
  dataType : ‘json’,
  data: “lang=”+lang,
    success: function(data){
    if(data.error === true){
    $( “#dialog-message2” ).text(data.msg).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( “close” );[removed]=location.href;
                      }
                    }
                  });
            }else{...}
```

when the page refresh the language stil not changed but when return the message from ajax it work
so where im wrong
sorry for the bad english 
thanks

*** the problem was -> system/libraries/Session.php (the original file from the CodeIgniter_2.0.2.zip) -> i download http://codeigniter.com/wiki/File:CI_1.5.1_with_Session.zip/ and no problems

Comment: If you've answered this question, please add an answer and mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the problem was -> system/libraries/Session.php (the original file from the CodeIgniter_2.0.2.zip) -> i download http://codeigniter.com/wiki/File:CI_1.5.1_with_Session.zip/ and no problems